# Matching characters if not first character

Tags: regex

I am having to pull out equations from a list and split them apart by operator sign (left and right).
The issue I am running into is the first or second character may or may not be negative.

So for example:

```
$number = "-7.89-2.45";
preg_split ('/[\+\-×÷\*\/]+/', $number);
//expect: [0]=>-7.89 [1]2.45

$number = "7.89-2.45";
preg_split ('/[\+\-×÷\*\/]+/', $number);
//expect: [0]=>7.89 [1]2.45

$number = "-7.89--2.45";
preg_split ('/[\+\-×÷\*\/]+/', $number);
//expect: [0]=>-7.89 [1]-2.45
```

But the issue is that it does not split it accurately if the first character is a - it splits it to often. And if the second is a negative and subtracting it doesn't pull out the negative.
So I am trying to determine a regular expression to split them strictly by operator.

Comment: Try `(?!^-)[-+×÷*\/]+`

Comment: That does seem to work, but looking at it, it runs into issues when the expression has a negative as the second number. Ie: 36.24--24.58

Comment: So, what are your expectations? Please add all the details to the question.

Comment: I have updated the question for a bit more clarity, the new issue was something I had not expected to run into.

Comment: Try `'~\b[-+×÷*/]~u'`

Comment: Unfortunately tat one doesn't seem to work for any separation.
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/38e85e044d6182c40f9991db702981b2ecb4b8fa

Comment: You pasted my string literal into your string literal and corrupted the code. Use `$list = preg_split ('~\b[-+×÷*/]~u', $number);`

Comment: Ah, fail on my part. But that does seem to be working now. Thanks for the help. I'll dissect it on my own to see how it works. Please copy that to an answer though so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you may split on the operator symbols that come after digits.

Use

```
$list = preg_split ('~(?<=\d)[-+×÷*/]~u', $number);
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KmwEFO/2). The `(?<=\d)` is a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with a digit, then `[-+×÷*/]` matches any of the chars in the character class.

Or, in a more general case, a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) may suffice:

```
$list = preg_split ('~\b[-+×÷*/]~u', $number);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KmwEFO/1). Here, the symbols will only match after letters, digits and `_`.